# Using dictionary from database instead of enum

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ddd-repositories

I have to create an application that uses sql server stored procedures instead of ORM, with ASP.NET and WPF user interfaces.

My entities (`product` and `order`) contains properties `int ProductType` and `int DeliveryType`. Normally I use enum for things like this, but project's requirement is to use a `Dictionary`. I built repository in separate project to use SP and want to add separate ASP and WPF projects that uses this repo.

To store values of this dictionaries I want to create sql tables that simply contains id and product/delivery name and pass them to `Dictionary<int, string>` and use this in applications, but I don't know where I should put logic for it so could I use this in both applications. Does anyone have an idea what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You have covered about 4 or 5 different topics. I'm not on-board with the "project's requirement is to use a `Dictionary`" comment, I don't fully understand. Nevertheless - this feels like some data access 'layer' that you need. Which would expose a series of entities/models mapped over from the DB that maybe another layer (containing more business-type logic) could call on. So that's 2 projects. Then on top of that can be any project/app/interface that requires the data in given business cases. But this is a huge question, and the answer can only be subjective. Which is why this is a comment.

Comment: Create a library that you can re-use. It can be a simple .dll or a nuget package or you could even pull that project into any solutions that need it. Think about how you would use an ORM in multiple projects. You just reference it, do the same with your library.